# Magento module works on localhost but not on remote host

Tags: magento

I know this is a silly question, but I've investigated thoroughly all the uppercases and lowercases on all filenames, directories and class names. All seem already correct. However, on remote host somehow the block file .phtml is not loaded. The layout xml is already loaded because I can see the CSS and JS files are loaded.

Just FYI, the admin backend works perfectly, only the frontend block that is not loaded. Not sure why the frontend block file is not loaded on remote host.

I gave my module name something like this ModuleABCD. Is it ok with several uppercases consecutively? Thanks in advance for any reply.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <modulename_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>modulename.css</name></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>modulename.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
          <block type="modulename/modulename" name="modulename" template="modulename.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </modulename_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Post the relevant layout XML which specifies your template path. Also, are you seeing an invalid template error in var/log/system.xml? Does the block class instance get created? Are the theme settings the same? Have the remote caches been refreshed?

Comment: Thanks benmarks. I check the var/log directory and it's empty which I assume there is no error or exception took place. The block class doesn't get instantiated because the block .php file doesn't get executed. Theme is using default, no setup change here all are default. Cache is disabled, var/cache has been removed (although it's recreated again everytime I access the site).

Answer (score 1):

Given that your layout file seems to be getting loaded, I recommend you do the following in a `./demo.php` file which you can run from your browser at http://site.com/demo.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);

include 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::getBlockClassName('classgroup/blockname');

Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('classgroup/blockname'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, benmarks. The script above gave me "file not found" error. Now I know where the culprit is. It seems I gave the wrong name for the .php block file (ModuleABCD.php). Because Magento will look for Moduleabcd.php even though the class name is Company_ModuleABCD_Block_ModuleABCD. Well, every day is a new lesson for me :). Thanks for your help, sir!

Comment: It depends. If you specify `<block type="[class group]/moduleabcd" .../>` then what you wrote is correct. If you specify `<block type="[class group]/moduleABCD" .../>` then it will look for the *ModuleABCD.php* file. This is only an issue on case-sensitive filesystems, which I'm guessing your remote host is and your dev enviro isn't :-)